# Full Calendar, iCalendarPlugin, Vuejs, Laravel - How or when are events from plugin loaded?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar, icalendar

I have a Laravel Vuejs app using FullCalendar. I added the iCalendarPlugin

```
plugins: [
                    dayGridPlugin,
                    timeGridPlugin,
                    listPlugin,
                    interactionPlugin,
                    iCalendarPlugin
                ],
```

with a source.

```
  events: [{url: 'localhost:9000/assets/ics/Feiertage.ics', format: 'ics'}],
```

On any event I call from fullcalendarApi the getEvents() function in order to fetch all Events, but there isn't holiday included.

this is my mounted()

```
 mounted()
{
    this.init();
    this.$nextTick(() =>
    {
 
        let calendarApi = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi();
        logger.log("NextTick", calendarApi.getEvents());
       
    });
},

 async init()
    {
     let calendarApi = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi();
     logger.log("INIT", calendarApi.getEvents());
    },
```

on both logs the events array is empty.

Is there a specific method called in order to create the holiday events? If so, when is it called?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: fullCalendar makes an AJAX request to load the events. Obviously AJAX is asynchronous. I'd guess your logging attempts are happening before the AJAX request has completed. Either that or the request is failing somehow, or not parsing the events correctly. I'm sure you can use the Network and Console tools in your developer tools to look at timings, content etc.

Comment: P.S. AFAIK the events data format should be `events: {url: 'localhost:9000/assets/ics/Feiertage.ics', format: 'ics'}` as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/icalendar - not sure why you wrapped it in an array? The problem could be as simple as that, I guess.